# PHP class to JSON on several levels

Tags: php, json, object

I have a PHP class I would like to transform in a JSON on several levels like this type:

```
{"interface":{"Version":"0"},"Container":[{"id":"1","Element":[{"text":"Test","id":"0"},{"text":"Toto","id":"1"}]}]}
```

In my PHP class I have a function who returns the JSON of my private attributes who are arrays:

```
return (json_encode((get_object_vars($this)), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Private attributes of my class:

```
private $interface = '';
private $Container = array(array('id' => '1'));
private $Element = array('text' => 'Test', 'id' => '0');
```

Do you know how I could have a JSON like above ?

In pleasure to read you.

Comment: why not structuring your variables in a way that when you json_encode, the output will be exactly the one you need?

Comment: Thanks for you answer,

My JSON will be dynamic with a database, so I can't do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to structure it, working example: [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/S49M3M)

```
   class test {
    private $interface = '';
    private $Contenant = array(array('id' => '1'));
   //private $Element = array(array('text' => 'Test', 'id' => '0'));

    public function json(){

        $this->Contenant = array(
            array('id' => '1',
                 'Element' =>  array(array('text' => 'Test', 'id' => '0'))
                ),

        );

        return json_encode((get_object_vars($this)), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
}


$t = new test();
$encode = $t->json();

echo $encode;
```

OUTPUT

```
{"interface":"","Contenant":[{"id":"1","Element":[{"text":"Test","id":"0"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your class members but as long as they are accessible you can generate the JSON string. Below if the example of this

```
    $Contenant = array(array('id' => '1'));
    $Element = array('text' => 'Test', 'id' => '0');

    $json = json_encode(array('inerrface'=>array(
                        'content'=>$Contenant,
                        "Element"=>$Element
                          )     
                       )
                );
    echo $json ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the IteratorAggregate interface like in the following example

```
class YourClass implements IteratorAggregate {
    protected $member1 = array();
    protected $member2 = array();

    ...

    public function getIterator() {
        $tmpArr = array();

        // create the structure you want in $tmpArr

        return new ArrayIterator($tmpArr);
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$iterator = $myClass->getIterator();

$encodedData = json_encode($iterator);
```

As of PHP5.4 you have the JsonSerializable interface ready to use. With this interface, you cann use direct modifications like in the example given in: https://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php

have fun! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started, take a look at the constructor what data input requires. You could make a private function doing the same thing, assigning your values to the structure and then printing it:

```
class Test{

    private $data;

    public function __construct($version = 0, $records = array()){

        $data['interface'] = array('Version' => $version);
        $data['Container'] = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($records); $i++) {
            $data['Container'][$i] = $records[$i];
        }

        // your test input
        print_r(json_decode('{"interface":{"Version":"0"},"Container":[{"id":"1","Element":[{"text":"Test","id":"0"},{"text":"Toto","id":"1"}]}]}',true));
        // actual input
        print_r($data);
        // printing our actual data as json string
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function __destruct(){

    }

}

$element1 = array('text' => 'Test', 'id' => 0);
$element2 = array('text' => 'Toto', 'id' => 1);
$elements = array($element1, $element2);
$record = array('id' => 1, 'element' => $elements);
$records = array($record);

new Test(0, $records);
```